# tex4ht gives 'illegal storage address' error when trying to convert to odt

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

I am trying to convert a LaTeX document to opendocument with TeX4ht (on Windows/MiKTeX 2.9 32-bit). I am using the following command (as suggested on the [TeX4ht website](https://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn-commands.html#QQ1-9-38)):

```
D:\latex>htlatex mwe.tex "xhtml,ooffice" "ooffice/! -cmozhtf" "-coo -cvalidate"
```

My `mwe.tex` reads:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

The LaTeX calls of `htlatex.bat` are running fine, but the `tex4ht` call is giving an error `Illegal storage address`:

```
D:\latex>tex4ht mwe.tex  -i/tex4ht/ht-fonts/"ooffice/! -cmozhtf" -ewin32/tex4ht.env
----------------------------
tex4ht.c (2010-12-16-08:39 Windows MiKTeX)
tex4ht mwe.tex
  -i/tex4ht/ht-fonts/ooffice/!
  -cmozhtf
  -ewin32/tex4ht.env
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/base/win32/tex4ht.env)
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/tfm/public/amsfonts/cmextra/cmbsy5.tfm)

(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/cm/cmbsy.htf)
Searching `cmsy.htf' for `cmbsy5.htf'
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/cm/cmsy.htf)
--- error --- Illegal storage address    

D:\latex>t4ht mwe.tex "-coo -cvalidate" -ewin32/tex4ht.env
----------------------------
t4ht.c (2010-12-16-08:47 MiKTeX)
t4ht mwe.tex
  -coo
  -cvalidate
  -ewin32/tex4ht.env
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/base/win32/tex4ht.env)
Entering mwe.lg
Entering mwe.css
Entering mwe.tmp
```

`cmbsy.htf` and `cmsy.htf` are at the designated locations. So what is wrong here?

I have found [this workaround](http://de.comp.text.tex.narkive.com/atSR0Ohi/oolatex-illegal-storage-address) by Ulrike Fischer (in German), but my `tex4ht.env` already contains relative paths (`tex4ht.env` is dated 12 Jul 2011 and the workaround is from 17 Jun 2011, so I guess that problem is fixed already) and I do not have a `oolatex.bat` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\tex4ht`. The `htlatex.bat` in the scripts folder reads:

```
latex %5 \makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode %2.a.b.c.\input  %1
latex %5 \makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode %2.a.b.c.\input  %1
latex %5 \makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode %2.a.b.c.\input  %1
tex4ht %1  -i/tex4ht/ht-fonts/%3 -ewin32/tex4ht.env
t4ht %1 %4 -ewin32/tex4ht.env
```

Comment: I get the same error with your MWE, and with another MWE: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119012/how-to-get-utf-8-output-with-tex4ht-under-miktex-2-9

Comment: The problem is due to a file which miktex doesn't find: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2350/

Answer (score 1):

The first problem here is that the `minimal` is obviously not supported by `tex4ht` conversion to odt, there are probably some missing configurations. But `minimal` doc class isn't recommended for normal usage, so it should be no issue. Just use `article` document class.

The second problem is with your command line, it is better to use

```
mk4ht oolatex mwe
```

instead of your version